# Evaluate the integral $\int\int _{[0,1]^2} \max \left\{x,y\right\} dx\, dy$

Tags: integration, vector-spaces

Find the integral 
 $$\int\int _{[0,1] \times[0,1]} \max \left\{x,y\right\} dx \,dy$$

Answer (score 5):

This is not a surface integral, but simply an integral over a 2D region.  To evaluate it, simply break the integral up into two pieces: one where $x \gt y$, and vice-versa.  The integral is then equal to

$$\int_0^1 dx \, x \, \int_0^x dy + \int_0^1 dx \, \int_x^1 dy \, y = \frac13 + \frac12 \cdot \frac13 = \frac12$$

Comment: @ Ron : How have you break this integeral into two pieces, Please cleared me.

Comment: @Struggler: by considering the max function.  Plot it over the given region and you will see how the integral breaks up this way naturally.

Comment: Thank you so much for the prompt reply